# NMaximize with constraints vs. explicit Lagrange multiplier method

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Could you explain the reason why these two outputs are different?

```
NMaximize[{2 x + 3 y, x^2 + y^2 == 1}, {x, y}, Method -> "NelderMead"]

{3.60555, {x -> 0.554703, y -> 0.832049}}
```

```
NMaximize[{2 x + 3 y - λ (x^2 + y^2 - 1)}, {x, y, λ}, Method -> "NelderMead"]

{1.246398993423563*10^367, {x -> 1.10276*10^122, 
  y -> 2.35731*10^122, λ -> -1.84025*10^122}}
```

I thought the Lagrange multiplier method guarantees these two are the same.

Comment: The function $L(x,y,\lambda) = 2x+3y-\lambda(x^2+y^2-1)$ can be arbitratily large, for example take $L(x,0,-1) = x^2+2x-1$ and then take $x \to +\infty$. Read the [Lagrange multiplier theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier#Statement) again.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems the problem is the consequence of a misunderstanding of the mathematics instead of a programming issue on Mathematica or Wolfram Language.  The OP should not be discouraged by this cleaning-up policy that aims to curate on-topic Q&A. OP's future [good questions](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3) , answers and comments are welcome.

Comment: @rhermans Agree, but I do have an off-topic question: Why do you provide a big brother link instead of the [clean link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: @user293787 better to bring that unrelated conversation to the [chat].

Comment: The answer with associated link by @user64494 I think should help explain why this second method will not work as coded. I agree with @ rhermans as to why this should be closed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a math question, not a Mathematica question. You incorrectly understand Lagrange multipliers. The Lagrange multiplier method does not consist in the maximization of the Lagrange function, but in the solution of a certain system of equations derived from it (see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) for info). The following works well:

```
Solve[
  D[2 x + 3 y - λ (x^2 + y^2 - 1), x] == 0 && 
  D[2 x + 3 y - λ (x^2 + y^2 - 1), y] == 0 && 
  D[2 x + 3 y - λ (x^2 + y^2 - 1), λ ] == 0, 
  {x, y, λ }
]

(* Out:
{{x -> -(2/Sqrt[13]), y -> -(3/Sqrt[13]), λ -> -(Sqrt[13]/2)}, 
 {x -> 2/Sqrt[13], y -> 3/Sqrt[13], λ -> Sqrt[13]/2}}`
*)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering to my question.
Now I understand why the second method does not work.
Then, what exactly is the algorithm of the first method?
Is it like Newton method minimizing the gradient to find local extrema?

Comment: Although I understand that the analytical way that you kindly showed a code here works, I need to understand the numerical way because I am willing to port the first method to fortran. As the failure of the first method implies, the Nelder–Mead method works for maximizing or minimizing evaluation function, not for finding local extrema, do I understand correctly?